# Creating ThreadPoolExecutor in spring cause memory leak?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading

I am working with Spring, and in a `RequestMap` method I have code like below:

```
@RequestMap
public void someMethod() {
    ThreadPoolExecutor executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(N);
    executor.submit(new Runnable());
    executor.submit(new Runnable());
}
```

Then I keep get OOM error even every `Runnable` should be finished in seconds. After analysing the heap dump, I found there are thousands `Thread` objects.

Then I changed `executor` to singlton with `Executors.newCachedThreadPool`, this problem was fixed.

As far as my understand, after the method returned, there is no reference to the thread pool, so it should be garbage-collected, but the fact is the thread still on the heap. Why?

Comment: If you want to run things in parallel, consider using something like rxjava  so you don't have to deal with the threads/pools yourself.

Comment: you may want to look into spring async for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this will leak memory. [As it says in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html):

> An unused `ExecutorService` should be shut down to allow reclamation of its resources.

Shut down the executor ([`executor.shutdown()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown--)), or reuse it.

Comment: After the request is finished, there are no references to `executor`, why did the threads and the `executor` not be garbage collected?

Comment: because threads live outside the regular garbage collection lifecycle of the scope you're in.

Comment: @LucasHolt You mean the threads will keep exitsing in JVM after they have finished their jobs?

Comment: @user6690200 not normal threads, but threads in a pool don't finish. When they've finished one task they wait for more.