# Whether a java thread pool that is no longer referenced needs to perform shutdown?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

Whether a java thread pool that is no longer referenced needs to perform shutdown?Does jvm automatically release thread resources?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Could you give a short example code that shows what local variable you mean? Please [edit] your question and add the code, and use the `{}` button to format it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#shutdown()):

> A pool that is no longer referenced in a program AND has **no remaining
>   threads** will be shutdown automatically.

However, by default, the threads in the pool will not terminate automatically, they will keey waiting for new tasks. So the resources will not be released.

> If you would like to ensure
>   that unreferenced pools are reclaimed even if users forget to call
>   shutdown(), then you must arrange that unused threads eventually die,
>   by setting appropriate keep-alive times, using a lower bound of zero
>   core threads and/or setting allowCoreThreadTimeOut(boolean).

And in my personal [experience](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49759394/creating-threadpoolexecutor-in-spring-cause-memory-leak), I have got `OutOfMemory` error because did not call `shutdown` or `allowCoreThreadTimeOut`.